# Use protected hierarchy custom settings to store sensitive information

Tags: apex, customsetting

We are thinking to store sensitive user specific keys in protected hierarchy custom settings. Is this secure place where only user can access data. We don't want this data to be visible to anyone other than user. let us know if it is right choice?

Comment: Is your app appexchange application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protected Custom Settings are *not* available to the user through Salesforce Setup. Protected Custom Settings and Custom Metadata are available only to code within the boundary of the managed package owning that entity.

You can use this functionality as desired - in the case of Protected Custom Settings - if any only if you implement a custom UI that exposes each user's instance to them. It's available only in a managed package. Outside a managed package, you cannot use Protected metadata. There is no out-of-the-box functionality that exposes data to a single user only, and not to users that have View All Data permission.

Answer (score 2):

Use of Protected `custom metadata types` is one more option in list. Also, you can access them through SOQL query. If you are using this in appexchange application, you don't have to use any post install script. An Upgradable type metadata would be best.They can be upgraded through new release of package.

Comment: The OP specifies "user specific keys". Since Custom Metadata cannot have lookups to User, but Custom Settings can be indexed per-user, that might be an argument in favour of Custom Settings.